# While saving getting error and product is not saved In Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, save

While creating the new product, entering all the values trying to save the

product below error is displayed not saving the product.

https://prnt.sc/ireqyg.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try re indexing?

Comment: Open var/log/exception.log and check error first

Comment: Catalog rule indexing failed.

Comment: Stock Item with id "abc" does not exist. @ІгорКлимчук

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this link too, it seems to be something you are looking for:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13326